# When registering a custom grunt task can I iterate through another task's targets?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

If I'm creating a custom grunt task can it iterate through targets of another task? Say I have this in my initConfig:

```
    clean: {
        target1: {
            // etc etc
        },
        target1: {
            // etc etc
        }
    }
```

and I'm registering a task:

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', function() {
    var run = [];

    // Loop through the targets in 'clean', comparing them 
    // with details passed in in my arguments array...

    grunt.task.run(run);
});
```

I'd essentially like to query the targets in tasks and dynamically build my array of things to run.

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options: 
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config

> grunt.config
>
> Get or set a value from the project's Grunt configuration. This method
>   serves as an alias to other methods; if two arguments are passed,
>   grunt.config.set is called, otherwise grunt.config.get is called.

```
grunt.config([prop [, value]])
```

> grunt.config.get
>
> Get a value from the project's Grunt configuration. If prop is
>   specified, that property's value is returned, or null if that property
>   is not defined. If prop isn't specified, a copy of the entire config
>   object is returned. Templates strings will be recursively processed
>   using the grunt.config.process method.

```
grunt.config.get([prop])
```